# Different route rendering on target="_blank" for react router Link tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Even though the Link has "to" attribute set to the correct route, the same is not loading on clicking. Another route within react-router gets loaded in its place.

This is the code:

---

App.js

```
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);

  // useEffect to stop infinite looping problem with state
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const loggedInInfo = localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn");

    if (loggedInInfo === "1") {
      setIsLoggedIn(true);
    }
  }, []);
```

Inside return()

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact>
      <Redirect to="/login" />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/login">
      {!isLoggedIn && <Login onFormSubmit={handleFormSubmit} />}
    </Route>
    <Route path="/home-page">
      {isLoggedIn && <HomePage onLogout={handleLogout} />}
      {!isLoggedIn && <Redirect to="/login" />}
    </Route>
    <Route path="/approved-factory-assy-test">
      {isLoggedIn && <ApprovedFactoryAssyTest onLogout={handleLogout} />}
      {!isLoggedIn && <Redirect to="/login" />}
    </Route>
    <Route path="*">
      <h1>Page not found!</h1>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
```

Navbar.js

```
<div className="sub-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><Link className="link" to='/approved-factory-assy-test' target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">Approved Factory Assy Test</Link></li>
```

Comment: Please provide the related code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

I suspect when the app opens in the new window and browser context that the initial `isLoggedIn` state being false for the initial render is immediately bouncing the user *off* the `"/approved-factory-assy-test"` route. The issue is that the initial state matches the unauthenticated state, i.e. `false`.

```
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = React.useState(false); // <-- initially false
```

...

```
<Route path="/approved-factory-assy-test">
  {isLoggedIn && <ApprovedFactoryAssyTest onLogout={handleLogout} />}
  {!isLoggedIn && <Redirect to="/login" />} // <-- bounce user to login
</Route>
```

## Solution

Try to use more accurate initial state. Initialize the `isLoggedIn` state *from* localStorage, and use a `useEffect` hook to persist local state changes *to* localStorage.

Example:

```
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = React.useState(() => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn")) ?? false;
});

React.useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", JSON.stringify(isLoggedIn));
}, [isLoggedIn]);
```

Now renders correct component on initial render based on initial `isLoggedIn` state value.

```
<Route path="/approved-factory-assy-test">
  {isLoggedIn
    ? <ApprovedFactoryAssyTest onLogout={handleLogout} />
    : <Redirect to="/login" />
  }
</Route>
```